# Aws codebuild for .net framework 4.7.2

Tags: asp.net, linux, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

iam having the code in .net framework with the version 4.7.2 and followed the code by searching the web, and whenever I try to build it using the build folder name it shows the issue as exit status 1, can caybody please help in providing the buildspec.yml with the above mentioned configuration and with os as linux.

I expect the buildspec.yml file for the .net framework with version 4.7.2 and os as linux-x64, fot this I have used the following buildspec.yml and log as "dotnet build test-api/test-api.csproj failed with exit status 1" and I checked the path,folder,name everything, but can't know how to solve this error"

version: 0.2

phases:
install:
runtime-versions:
dotnet: 5.0
#dotnet: latest - Latest resolve to 3.1, check this issue https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/issues/414

pre_build:
commands:
- echo Restore started on `date`
- dotnet restore test-api/test-api.csproj

build:
commands:
- echo Build started on `date`
- dotnet build test-api/test-api.csproj
- echo Test started on `date`
- dotnet test test-api/test-api.csproj

post_build:
commands:
- echo Publish started on `date`
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-linux-platform-bundle-app.html
- dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64 -o ./ test-api/test-api.csproj

artifacts:
files:
- ./**/*

Comment: This question could be improved if you posted snippets of the build log and your existing build configuration.